# Telerik: Add Edit Functionality to Grid?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

OK... I'm very very rusty, so please be kind ;)

I'm building web form application, using a Grid.  I have the grid populating with my data correctly (considering this is a rough draft) and now I'm trying to add the edit function.  I created a combobox, which displays correctly when I choose "edit".  This is about as far as I've managed to get plowing through Telerik's tutorials.  I want to update the row's status field with the selected item from the combobox. I'm just not getting my head around what to do next... the sad thing is I've done this before albeit long ago :(

My code is below... I would be very grateful for any nudges in the right direction.

```
 <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowAutomaticUpdates="True"
        CellSpacing="0" GridLines="None" AllowPaging="True">
<MasterTableView>

<RowIndicatorColumn Visible="True" FilterControlAltText="Filter RowIndicator column">
<HeaderStyle Width="20px"></HeaderStyle>
</RowIndicatorColumn>

<ExpandCollapseColumn Visible="True" FilterControlAltText="Filter ExpandColumn column">
<HeaderStyle Width="20px"></HeaderStyle>
</ExpandCollapseColumn>

    <Columns>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter column column" 
            UniqueName="column" DataType="System.String" DataField="Make">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter column1 column" 
            UniqueName="column1" DataType="System.String" DataField="Model">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter column2 column" 
            UniqueName="column2" DataType="System.String" DataField="Year">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
          <telerik:GridBoundColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter column2 column" 
            UniqueName="column3" DataType="System.String" DataField="Status" >
     </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Category" ItemStyle-Width="240px">

                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <telerik:RadComboBox RenderMode="Lightweight" runat="server" ID="RadComboBox2" DataTextField="Status" 
                             DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1" DataValueField="ID" >                           
                            </telerik:RadComboBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>

<ItemStyle Width="240px"></ItemStyle>

              </telerik:GridTemplateColumn> 

                    <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn FooterText="EditCommand footer" UniqueName="EditCommandColumn"

                        HeaderText="Edit" HeaderStyle-Width="100px" UpdateText="Update">

<HeaderStyle Width="100px"></HeaderStyle>

                    </telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>

    </Columns>

<EditFormSettings>
<EditColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter EditCommandColumn column"></EditColumn>
</EditFormSettings>
</MasterTableView>

<FilterMenu EnableImageSprites="False"></FilterMenu>
    </telerik:RadGrid>
```

Thanks in advance for any and all help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of the ComboBox for this if you want it to update immediately. Just make sure you add the attribute `AutoPostBack="true"` to your ComboBox

```
protected void RadComboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get the RadComboBox
    var comboBox= (RadComboBox)sender;

    // Get the item from the grid (RadComboBox parent)
    GridDataItem item = (GridDataItem)comboBox.NamingContainer;

    item["column3"].text = comboBox.SelectedText; // can't remember the exact syntax on this

}
```

Alternatively, you could just use the `RadGrid_ItemCommand` event that will fire when you click your update button.

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.CommandName == RadGrid.EditCommandName)
   {
       // For Normal mode
       GridDataItem item = e.Item as GridDataItem;

       RadComboBox comboBox = item.FindControl("RadComboBox2") as RadComboBox;

       item["column3"].text = comboBox.SelectedText; // can't remember the exact syntax on this
   }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @dstepan , it's starting to get my brain firing again ;)  but it doesn't seem to be quite right. For one odd thing, Intellisense is telling me it doesn't know "RadComboBox2"

Comment: Intellisense won't know RadComboBox2 because it's nested within the RadGrid. However, if you wire up the event `OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadComboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged"` and add the `AutoPostBack` attribute, you should be able to hit the break point inside that event. You'll have to get the control from the GridDataItem (`item.FindControl("RadComboBox2")`) or by using the sender in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event.

Comment: I'll try it and let you know @dstepan ... I'm sincerely grateful for your time!

Comment: No joy @dstepan ...It  seems there're some syntactical issues, as well as figuring out how I'm hooking into the actual values.  Ran out of time for this evening but I'll be tackling it again in the morning. Thank you again, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Can you add some code-behind so we can see what you have so far?

Comment: Hello again @dstepan 

I'm getting absolutely nowhere with this, and although I may be rusty I can't believe it's really so difficult :(  My most recent attempt to extract a value from the row was:
     protected void RadGrid1_UpdateCommand(object source, GridCommandEventArgs e)
        {
             
            if (e.CommandName == "Update")
            {
                GridEditableItem editItem = e.Item as GridEditableItem;
             
                string status = editItem["column3"].Text.ToString();

            }
and like everything else I've tried I'm getting nowhere.

Comment: OK... I'm afraid I'm going to jinx myself but I think I finally figured out the key, so to speak.  I had to set DataKeyNames, and then get my values from those, ie:

                var editableItem = ((GridEditableItem)e.Item);
                var status = (string)editableItem.GetDataKeyValue("Status");

Comment: Getting the value form the data key doesn't help in your scenario, does it? You want to update the value in the grid. The DataKeyValue is included when the grid is bound, and it's my understanding that it's not editable. Just to be clear, you want to 1) click edit 2) show drop down; show update button 3) select an item from drop down 4) click update 5) status text is updated in the grid. Is that correct?

Comment: @ dstepan welllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll here's the thing... since you were kind enough to originally try to help me, I realized I'd have to change my game plan and do the updates via a couple discrete stored proc.  So I "think" that I need to extract these values, the rows that represent them and then update the tables that they came from...